# Rails model constants with hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, constants

I have added some constants to a model say `MyModel.rb` as shown below.

```
MY_CONST = {
  :foo =>"Some Name for Foo",
  :bar =>"Some Name for Bar"
  }
```

Also I have saved string `foo` as the column value in a table record.

```
@m = MyModel.find(1)
@m.column_name #=> foo
```

Now in my view I need to show "Some Name for Foo" as the output for `@m.column_name` instead of `foo`

I tried `MyModel::MY_CONST[:foo]` and it prints `"Some Name for Foo"` as the output. But I don't know how to pass `@m.column_name` to `MyModel::MY_CONST[....]` dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
MyModel::MY_CONST[@m.column_name]
```

or

```
MyModel::MY_CONST[@m.column_name.to_sym]
```

Comment: I tried `MyModel::MY_CONST[@m.column_name]` it never worked for me, (that's why I posted the question)  
But `MyModel::MY_CONST[@m.column_name.to_sym]` works, thanks a lot.

Comment: if you want to run `MyModel::MY_CONST[@m.column_name]` change `:foo =>"Some Name for Foo",`  to `"foo" =>"Some Name for Foo",
`

Comment: Thanks a lot Salil. I understand now, I really never thought about it.